# PHP Create a unique number from 1 to 9 using userid

Tags: php, random, integer

In order to color code each row of a calendar I'd like to be able to create a unique integer from 1 to 9 using the field userid.  I need to use the color in another part of the calendar to display the student assigned to the instructor.

Bear in mind that userID can be any length.

At first I thought of using the least significant digit, but that won't work for user IDs 01, 21, 22 etc.

Then I thought of adding the left to the right, eg userID 22 = 2+2=4, but that won't work either.

Any ideas how I might create a unique 0-9 integer based on the users ID?

Comment: I might be completely missing what you are trying to do - but aren't the user ID's already unique?

Comment: @BenGriffiths "Bear in mind that userID can be any length." User Id `1337` is not in `1..9`.

Comment: This problem is very similar to graph coloring. But I think you made it unsolveable. If you have more than 9 users you have to ensure that after selecting a unique color for each no 10th user will every be displayed together with any 8 of the previous 9 as you don't have a 10th color for him.

Comment: @Basti Ah I misread, I assumed he meant he only wanted number digits, not a single number digit :)

Comment: @Basti I don't mind if user 10, 11, 12 etc all have a generic color eg grey.  It is very similar to graphing I'd just like to assign the first 9 instructors in my calendar a unique (pastel) color.  But I have multiple clubs with a various qty of instructors, usually about 4 or 5 each.

Comment: Have a go on mensi's solution then. Just store which color you assigned already and if all 9 colors have been used, use grey henceforth. If you need this assignment to be permanent, store it in the database.

Answer (score 4):

Any function mapping [0..N] to [1..9] will have collisions if N is larger than 9 and therefore there does not exist a scheme that maps them uniquely.

What you can do in your case is to just go through the userIDs and assign them the next free number if you have not seen this userID before. This is a simple for-loop + an array.

Pseudocode:

```
colors = array()
for userid in userids_to_color:
    if userid not in colors:
        colors[count(colors)] = userid
```

Colors is then a mapping index (=color number) to userid. You can break out of the loop if `count(colors)` becomes greater than your maximal number of colors.